# how do i initialize a pointer with 3 levels of indirection? c++

Tags: pointers, dynamic, initialization, dereference, indirection

*shaded boxes are pointers and elements that hold the values are on the heap*

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DICD.png)

I pretty much need to come up with the statements to implement the diagram. I am so thrown off by initializing something pointed to with 3 levels of indirection that is on the heap.

please help me...
this is what i have

```
int *c{ new int(18) },
 ***a{ new int**(&c) },
 *e{ new int(22) },
 **b;
b = &e;

    b = nullptr;
e = nullptr;
a = nullptr;
c = nullptr;

delete b, e, a, c;
```

Comment: based on the diagram, `a` is not supposed to go via `c`

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to get your head around if you use a named variable for every box in your diagram, and stick to one initialization or assignment at a time

Comment: Note that the programming field is not at all like the restaurant business. More stars is not generally considered "better" in any way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Example for the pointer a.

```
int*** a;
a = new int**;
*a = new int*;
**a = new int(18);
```